# SELECTING Multiple Rows with an Array and then INSERT to another statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to SELECT data from one table based on the ID and then INSERT the returned data in to another table.

My code is:

```
<?php
    require '../../db-config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['course'])) {
        $selected_courses = '('. implode(',', $_POST['course']) .')';
        $status = 'Live';
        $active = 'Y';

        $stmt = "SELECT id, coursetitle FROM courses WHERE id IN ". $selected_courses ." 
                 AND status = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $selected_courses);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $coursetitle);

        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO distributor_course_settings
                                  (id, active, coursetitle) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("iss", $id, $active, $coursetitle);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
?>
```

> The error I am getting is: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   bind_param() on boolean

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: what is `$stmt->bind_result($id, $coursetitle);`? It is after the execute statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can perform both actions (select and insert) in one query. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO distributor_course_settings
(id, distributor, active, coursetitle) 
SELECT id, '$distributer', 'Y', coursetitle 
FROM courses 
WHERE id IN ". $selected_courses ." 
AND status = 'Live'
```

the values in select statement can be anything like string, php variable or a subselet statment like:

```
   INSERT INTO distributor_course_settings
    (id, distributor, active, coursetitle) 
    SELECT id, (select distributer from distributor_course_settings where id = 12), 'Y', coursetitle 
    FROM courses 
    WHERE id IN ". $selected_courses ." 
    AND status = 'Live'
```

and if its a php variable, you statement could look like this:

```
 $stmt = "INSERT INTO distributor_course_settings
    (id, distributor, active, coursetitle) 
    SELECT id, '".$distributor."', 'Y', coursetitle 
    FROM courses 
    WHERE id IN ". $selected_courses ." 
    AND status = 'Live'"
```

Comment: This is working but there is a distributor column in the table distributor_course_settings and I want to insert the variable $distributor to that, how would I do that too?

Comment: Well at the moment I am only inserting into 3 columns in distributor_course_settings, I need to insert data in to the distributor column too.

Comment: I updated my answer but the answer to your question depends on where the value of distributer comes from: is it in a variable or just a string or from another query...

Comment: It's a set variable $distributor = "Company" is set at the top of the page.